# DateHelper Include Missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Do I need to include "actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb" to use DateHelper in my application?

I'm new to rails.

Answer (score 0):

No it should be included automatically already.

But keep in mind as its name (view helper) suggests, you can only use it from views, but not from controllers (or even models).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can use right out the box in your view.

But if your concern is your controller then the answer is: yes. You should include it in your controller in order to use it, **or even better**, just access them through `view_context` like this: `view_context.your_helper_method(some_param)`